# Is it possible to query or sort the document based on the size of an array inside the json document in marklogic?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

```
{
  "name": "ruby",
  "phone": [
    {
      "type": "mobile",
      "number": 12345678
    },
    {
      "type": "office",
      "number": 2433242
    }
  ]
}
```

My problem here is, I just want to sort the documents like the one mentioned above based on the size of phone array.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a [Template Driven Extraction (TDE)](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/TDE) with a column that has the size of the phone array, and then search and sort with the Optic API.

Unfortunately, you cannot simply create a path-range-index with the following XPath, because it isn't an indexable XPath expression:

```
/array-node('phone')/count(node())
```